Boundedness of derivatives?
I want to ask that $L^2$-boundedness (uniformly in $j$) of the following:
\begin{equation}
    \|D^{2k}\big((2^{-2j}+|x|^2)^{k+\frac{1}{2}}\varphi(x)\big)\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}, \quad j,k\in\mathbb{N},
\end{equation}
where $D$ is a differential operator and $\varphi\in B(0,1)$ is a compactly supported function.
To get boundedness, I first consider to show
\begin{equation}
|D^{2k}\big((2^{-2j}+|x|^2)^{k+\frac{1}{2}}\big)| \lesssim p(x)
\end{equation}
where $p(x)$ is a some polynomial because product of polynomial and $\varphi$ gives $L^2$-bound easily.
If coefficients of $k$ are same (i.e. replacing $D^k$), it may be bounded for some constants.
In this case, it is different since the order of $D$ is bigger than $(1+|x|^2)^{k+\frac{1}{2}}$.
It does not matter for $k+\frac{1}{2}-2k\ge0$ since it may vanish supported region. However, I cannot determine when the other case. Heuristically, it may blow-up near $0$, or is not bounded uniformly in $j$. Am I wrong?
The thought of this question is came from proof of Lemma A.3 in Appendix A in here: arxiv or doi.

Define $\psi_{j,k} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\psi_{j,k}(x) = (2^{-2j}+|x|^2)^{k+\frac{1}{2}}$. What does $(D^{2k}\phi_{j,k})(x)$ mean ? I have seen a similar notation in evans, pg 619, appendix A, It denotes $$ |D^{2k}\psi_{j,k}|^2 = \sum_{|\alpha|=2k}|D^{\alpha}\psi_{j,k}|^2.$$
Is this what you are following? @Idkwhat

@Sam Yes it is.

From the calculation I have done, it seems like norm is uniformly bounded if and only if $k < \frac{n+1}{2}$ @Idkwhat This is based on the fact that the function is of order $|x|^{1-2k}$ for large values of $j$ near the origin.
